# How to add a new property in object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one obj like

```
var obj = {
        name : "Jenny",
        roll : "1000"
}
```

Now I want to add a new property in obj called `grade`.

after that my object looks like

```
var obj = {
        name : "Jenny",
        roll : "1000",
        grade :"7"
}
```

I am not getting any method from `obj` `obj[op]=value`. How to achive that.

Comment: When using bracket notation, wrap the property key in quotes. `obj.grade = '7';` or `obj['grade'] = '7';`

Comment: @Tushar why not answer :)

Comment: Because it's a dupe of a dupe of a dupe of a dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an object so you can not do `obj[op] = value`

Instead you can do `obj.op = value`

In this case, `obj.grade = 7` will serve the purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this.

```
   Object.defineProperty(obj, 'grade', {
      value: '7'
    });
```

Comment: Would you please explain why would you downvote this?